# WPF datagrid bound to datatable

Tags: c#, wpf

To set the scene; I have 2 datatables, assets and models, and a datagrid which is bound to the asset datatable; the tables are populated via a database pull. When creating a new asset the user will pick the model from a dropdown list of models, the models combobox is bound to the models datatable and shows the display name, from the model table, rather than the model ID. The text field of the model dropdown updates the new assets datatable and shows as the ID, which is how the asset table is linked to the model table and is what is required at export time.

This all currently works as expected however for user friendliness i want to display the display name in the datagrid view of assets rather than the ID however i dont want to change the fact that the id exists in the asset table as that is what is required at export time.

In a combobox i can use displaymemberpath to shown a different value however i am unable to find an equivalent for the datagrid or a way to do what I am after, any help appreciated.

WPF code for datagrid (Bound to AssetCollection):

```
<DataGrid Name="newAssetRecords" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="AssetTag" Binding="{Binding AssetTag,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

WPF code for combobox (Bound to Model Collection):

```
<ComboBox Name="combobox_newModel" SelectedValue="{Binding Model, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="[DisplayName]" SelectedValuePath="[SysID]" IsEditable="True"/>
```

C# code for asset class

```
public class AssetsCollection
 {
    public string SysID { get; set; }
    public string SysUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string AssetTag { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
 }
```

C# code for model class

```
public class ModelCollection
 {
    public string SysID { get; set; }
    public string SysUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
 }
```

The asset's model is a sysid which would exist in the model collection.

Now obviously I haven't posted all the initialisation code for the classes or the data retrieval but hopefully that is enough to help.

Comment: You can add another `DataGridTextColumn` and Bind it to the `Model.DisplayName` property? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In theory yes I could but I need to pull the displayname based on what the asset model sysid is. So, asset.model=5 therefore displayname = model.sysid = 5.displayname.

Comment: In that case use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and define the template with `TextBlock` using `MulitBinding` and a `Converter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Hide columns:

```
Data.Columns["IdColumn"].Visible = false;
```

And you can set the Header:

```
Data.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Something";
```

If you got some example-code we could possibly find some generic approches..

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated my main post.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, I added a new string to the Asset class called ModelName and updated it when the combobox dropdown was closed via a lookup to the models table. (I also had to implement inotifyproperty on the asset collection)

Thanks for all your help.